# conditional REGex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, html

i retrive a text  from a div with the following options : "1,000" $  OR   "1,000.57" $  "20" OR  "20.5"

i need to extract the number only ( int \ float) without the comma sign and without the dollar sign. 
as for now im using the following mask : /\d+/g;

but with this mask i get the number when it doesnt include comma and it get the number only to the decimal point ( e.g 290.5 -> 290 instead of it's original ) 
i'm looking for the correct regex mask for that so i will be able to parse the number after i get it .

Comment: Idk why your question is downvoted.  this seems perfectly legit to me.

Comment: so in short you want just the numbers with the decimals regardless how long but without letters (currency symbols) and without  a comma separating the 1000 mark of the values? e.g "1,000" $ and "1,000.45867" $ to be 1000 and 1000.45867 respective? - will this div only take one value or will it take multiple values separated by something?

Comment: Ah, perhaps I misread the question.  I thought you were trying to parse out that entire string, including quotes and ORs from a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
var str = ... // gets the text from the div
var num = Number(str.replace(/\$|,/g, '')); // converts the string to a number
                                            // (either a float or an int, depending
                                            // on the input string)
```

Comment: work like a charm! 
thanks :) 
i'm so eager to learn regEx - it's a life saver

Comment: Yeah, regex is awesome! If you are looking for some resources, I used [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) website when I started learning. [RegexOne](http://regexone.com/) is another cool resource with some interactive lessons.

Comment: I'll check that out.. Cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do it in 2 steps.  I would focus my regex on the quotation marks, something like `/"[0-9,.$]"/g`.  I can't remember if you have to escape the `.` (like `\.`) inside `[]`s.  Then, after extracting the whole, original number, I would have other code to remove the comma, dollar sign, spaces, etc.